# Size MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf

Why don't i see equality of size WPF form between source and compilation?
I mean that the status bar and the button look different between the images. They have a different position. The first image before compilation. The second image after.

What do I do wrong?

Sorry for the question of a beginner.

[image: First example]

[image: Second example]

```
<Window x:Class="WebDownloader.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WebDownloader"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Initialized="Window_Initialized" Closed="Window_Closed" ResizeMode="NoResize" Height="190" Width="225.395">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="MainButton" Content="Done" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="135,108,0,0" Click="MainButton_Click" FontFamily="Times New Roman"/>
    <StatusBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,133,0,0" Width="209" Height="18" FontFamily="Times New Roman">
        <StatusBarItem Content="StatusBarItem" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Width="78" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </StatusBar>

</Grid>
```

Comment: You have alignment set to Left and Top, but are positioning it on the bottom right of the window.

Comment: Have you checked your designer's zoom level?

Comment: Thank you all. Sorry for the stupid question. I was helped by the advice of JMK. I didn't notice it self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are using a static layout with fixed sizes and margins to place the items. You really should not layout a WPF app in this way.

Use a relative layout and use the `Grid` like it should be used: with rows and columns.

I removed all properties which aren't needed for the layout to keep this sample as short as possible.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Done" 
            Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Width="75"
            Margin="0 0 5 5"/>
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="2" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StatusBarItem Content="StatusBarItem"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

[image: Example]

**Info**

You can remove the `Height` and `Width` property of your `Window` and using `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` when you want your UI to be as big as it has to be to show all content.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/wpf-windows-overview) is worth a look; it gives a nice overview of WPF windows.

You can control a window's `height` and `width`, e.g.

```
<Window Height="200" Width="300">
    <!-- Content here -->
</Window>
```

Gives you a window 300 wide and 200 tall.

Additionally you can specify a minimum and maximum value - this is useful when you want your users to be able to resize your windows, e.g.

```
<Window Height="200" Width="300" MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="500">
    <!-- Content here -->
</Window>
```

Gives you a window 200 tall and between 200 and 500 wide with a default width of 300.

You can specify a design height and width like this

```
<Window Height="200" Width="300" DesignWidth="500" DesignHeight="500">
    <!-- Content here -->
</Window>
```

This says "make my window 300 wide and 200 tall but make it 500 by 500 in my designer".

This being said, a better approach is often be to use `SizeToContent` so that your window fits your content. Like this

```
<Window SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <!-- Content here -->
</Window>
```